# How to convert object to object[]

Tags: c#

I have an `object` whose value may be one of several array types like `int[]` or `string[]`, and I want to convert it to a `string[]`. My first attempt failed:

```
void Do(object value)
{
    if (value.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        object[] array = (object[])value;
        string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll(array, item => item.ToString());
        // ...
    }
}
```

with the runtime error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.Object[]'`, which makes sense in retrospect since my `int[]` doesn't contain boxed integers.

After poking around I arrived at this working version:

```
void Do(object value)
{
    if (value.GetType().IsArray)
    {
        object[] array = ((Array)value).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll(array, item => item.ToString());
        // ...
    }
}
```

I guess this is OK, but it seems pretty convoluted. Anyone have a simpler way?

Comment: Looks good to me. What more could you want?

Comment: Arrays are always convoluted. Generic lists are far easier to work with. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to an array and *then* use LINQ. You can do it in a more streaming fashion, only converting to an array at the end:

```
var strings = ((IEnumerable) value).Cast<object>()
                                   .Select(x => x == null ? x : x.ToString())
                                   .ToArray();
```

(Note that this will preserve nulls, rather than throwing an exception. It's also fine for any `IEnumerable`, not just arrays.)

Comment: I think Linq's Cast does not use boxing. Is that true? If so, can't we have any problems converting some types?

Comment: @LuisFilipe: Yes, it does boxing. It won't do conversion from (say) `byte` to `int`, but it will box.

Comment: @JonSkeet: why can't Linq's Cast do conversion from byte to int. From my research that's not a custom conversion (at least it doesn't appear at VS metadata). Maybe this is too much off topic...

Comment: @LuisFilipe: Before .NET 3.5 SP1, it actually did. But now it basically does a cast to `T` - and given that the value would be a boxed `byte`, trying to unbox it to `int` would fail...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for your enlightenment; Even though i need to read the literature to fully understand it.

Comment: Perfectly ! I wasted 2 days for that ! I tried to convert an object array to string array or List<string>.

Answer (score 1):

`.ToArray` makes multiple memory allocations in [most cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427912/linq-cast-or-cast-inside-convertall-for-a-list/42428816#42428816), but there are few ways around it:

```
object value = new[] { 1, 2.3 };

IList list = value as IList;
string[] strings = new string[list.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    strings[i] = Convert.ToString(list[i]);
```

In most cases that might be a bit overkill and waste of vertical space, so I would use something like the accepted answer with an optional [null-conditional operator `?`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595) to check if the source is array:

```
string[] strings = (value as Array)?.Cast<object>().Select(Convert.ToString).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry, no.  "...value may be one of several array types like `int[]` or `string[]`..." Your initial cast using "as" will fail in either of these cases.  Not with an exception, but `array` will be null.  Array types are not covariant.   (better than Skeet?)

Comment: Thanks @MarcL. Like usual I didn't read the question carefully, and I was thinking of the `dynamic` `object[,]` arrays in `Interop.Excel`

Answer (score -2):

```
void Do(object value)
{
    if (value.GetType().IsArray)
    {
       string[] strings = ((object[]) value).Select(obj => Convert.ToString(obj)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: My question specifically rejects `(object[])value` due to possible runtime errors.