# linq .Cast<> or cast inside ConvertAll for a list

Tags: c#, linq, casting

Consider you have to convert `mylist` of type `List<T>` to `List<Base>` where `T` is subclass of `Base`

Are these solutions the same? Which has better performances, and why?
When should I prefer using the first or the second?

```
return mylist.Cast<Base>().ToList();

return mylist.ConvertAll(x => (Base)x);
```

Maybe the second solution could be better because mylist is converted directly.

In the first solution the list is converted to IEnumerable, then to list, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is your definition of "better"?

Comment: @DavidG I mean with better performance, I will edit the question

Comment: In that case, go read this https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @DavidG I really like the first part :o)

Comment: @Scancy Did you read the blog from Eric Lippert? Who is the winner of your horse race?

Comment: I'd expect it to vary depending on the types involved. In particular if `myList` was already implemented `IEnumerable<T>` then`Cast<T>()` will just return it again. If it's an `IEnumerable<T>` **and** a collection type then the `ToList()` would have some further optimisations it wouldn't have otherwise, which would be about equivalent to the preallocation that `ConvertAll` can do.

Comment: Eh, Eric's opinion is his opinion.  Sometimes you want an answer based on actual tests, sometimes you want a theoretical answer based on what you know about how something works-- that is why we have big O notation, among other things.

Comment: Well, this is not really so important, I wanted to understand a bit more about how all the conversion is made (so I expected a theoretical answer)

Comment: @JohnWu You know that Eric Lippert was one of the principal developers of the C# compiler?

Comment: @JohnWu Sure, but then I would expect a question like: "Why is A faster than B?"

Comment: Oh yes, I'll add "why" to the question, actually I was interested in that

Comment: @Scanzy So you want us to do the performance test for you? You should give us your test data - no I'm kidding. What keeps you away from a simple performance test to get rid of the Which and leave only the Why open?

Comment: Can you also write it `return myList.Select(a => (T)a).ToList()` ?

Comment: As @JonHanna said, performances could depend on the types involved, so I think some direct test could not give us the correct answer, I hope someone would explain the "why". However, I am using List<T>, I'll edit the question

Comment: @JohnWu yes you're right, but this is already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571819/difference-between-select-and-convertall-in-c-sharp

Comment: You say "In the first solution the list is converted to IEnumerable" - no, it's not. There is no conversion (or cast for that matter). The `.Cast<Base>()` does not cause an enumerable to be created. It only creates an object that effectively decorates the underlying list. There is no copying, conversion or casting performed by simply doing `.Cast<Base>()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `ConvertAll` makes 1 memory allocation, but `.Cast.ToList` more than one in most cases.

Most LINQ extensions (like `.Cast<T>()`) result in a deferred execution `IEnumerable<T>` that can't be cast to `ICollection<T>` (can't get the `.Count` of the result).

When the result can be cast to `ICollection<T>`, [`.ToList`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e276d6892241255b) and [`.ToArray`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d) can make just one memory allocation to copy the elements, but when it can't:

- initially 4 element buffer array is allocated for non-empty source
- when space is needed for more elements, new array is allocated with double the size of the previous one
- elements are copied from the old array to the new one, and the old array is later deallocated by the garbage collector.

**Update**

Surprisingly, the difference doesn't seem nowhere near as significant as I expected:

```
method      elapsed             ratio               count

Cast.ToList 00:00:14.4487329    1.3719890831991     123456789
ConvertAll  00:00:10.5312302    0.728868773261865

Cast.ToList 00:00:01.4959734    1.50233158227713    12345678
ConvertAll  00:00:00.9957678    0.665632016125407

Cast.ToList 00:00:00.1252968    2.45948743599897    1234567
ConvertAll  00:00:00.0509442    0.40658878161491

Cast.ToList 00:00:00.0082611    3.99145006839945    123456
ConvertAll  00:00:00.0020697    0.250535515380002

Cast.ToList 00:00:00.0008097    0.620558719826417   12345
ConvertAll  00:00:00.0013049    1.61145104895105

Cast.ToList 00:00:00.0001812    0.193207547169811   1234
ConvertAll  00:00:00.0009378    5.17578125

Cast.ToList 00:00:00.0001433    0.149501661129568   123
ConvertAll  00:00:00.0009587    6.68888888888889
```

So, **race your horses**!

```
int c = 123; var L = Enumerable.Range(0, c).ToList();

GC.Collect(); var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew(); L.Cast<object>().ToList(); sw1.Stop();

GC.Collect(); var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew(); L.ConvertAll(i => (object)i); sw2.Stop();

MessageBox.Show($"Cast.ToList\t{sw1.Elapsed}\t{(double)sw1.ElapsedTicks / sw2.ElapsedTicks}\n" +
                $"ConvertAll \t{sw2.Elapsed}\t{(double)sw2.ElapsedTicks / sw1.ElapsedTicks}");
```