# Why List<A> doesn't convert to List<B> on conversion using Select operator

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Consider the following piece of code, Here I can typecast `IEnumerable<A>` to `List<A>`, as that's what it contains internally, but when I use `Select` to transform the same collection to `IEnumerable<B>`, it is not `List<B>`, which I can only achieve by calling `ToList()`, which is a penalty in my actual code, due to millions records in the first collection. Is there a better way to achieve it, I wonder why `List<A>` doesn't transform into `List<B>`, if List is the underlying memory allocation

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new A { Id = 1 };

    IEnumerable<A> aList = new List<A> {a};

    ((aList as List<A>) != null); // True

    var bList = aList.Select(x => new B { Id = x.Id});

    ((bList as List<B>) != null);  // False
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Because it is done **lazy**...

Comment: Anyway to make it Eager execution, since ToList is not a very performance friendly call, since it internally copies to a new List

Comment: You cannot, since generics are invariant. The best you can do is to use [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Try to call `bList.GetType().FullName` to see the underlying type returned by Select method. In fact Select method create a wrapper iterator type that use your aList as data source.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms but the casting is of little help, hope MS have provided a eager version too

Comment: Thanks @Kalten its indeed a wrapper, which gets executed when we finally use it, purely Lazy execution

Comment: Well, honestly, needing this might be a sign of a wrong decision in your application design. "hope MS have provided a eager version too" --- it would be impossible: `A` and `B` are different types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427912/linq-cast-or-cast-inside-convertall-for-a-list

Comment: There is nothing to _copy_ to a new list, because Select does not create a new list. There is no `List<B>` created anywhere in your code, so you cannot have penatly copying it.

Comment: bList is of type IEnumerable<B>, IEnumerable<B> and List<B> are different types, so the result of your test is OK. You can try with: Console.WriteLine((bList as IEnumerable<B>) != null); // True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `bList` is an `IEnumerable<B>` where no value from `aList` has been converted yet. That conversion will happen for instance when you `foreach` over that list, or call `.ToList()` on it. This is the "lazy" aspect that the comments mention.

So your second test is right: it is *not* a `List<B>`.